Error by calling and executing StartVM and GetIp Functions

I'm currently automating a script to build a virtual machine, check its status, start the VM if necessary, and then retrieve its IP address. I'm using PowerShell in Proxmox for this task. Here's the script I'm working on. all Functions are separatley tested , they works
`  @`$BASE_URL ="...com:8006/api2/json"
$API_TOKEN = "" [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}  $NODE = "" $POOL = ""
function Create-Kali-VM { param ( [string]$vmId )  try {     $url = "$BASE_URL/nodes/$NODE/qemu/122/clone"     $cloneParams = @{ "newid" = $vmId; "pool" = $POOL; "full" = 1 }     $headers = @{ "Authorization" = "PVEAPIToken=$API_TOKEN" }     $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Method Post -Body $cloneParams      Write-Output "Kali VM $vmId has been successfully created."      Start-Sleep -Seconds 30      while ($true) {         $vmStatus = Check-VMStatus -vmId $vmId         Write-Output "Status of Kali VM $vmId is $vmStatus"         Start-Sleep -Seconds 30          if ($vmStatus -eq "stopped") {             Start-VM -vmId $vmId             Start-Sleep -Seconds 30             break         }         elseif ($vmStatus -eq "running") {             $ip = Get-VMIP -vmId $vmId             if ($ip) {                 Write-Output "User access to Kali VM $vmId using IP: $ip"                 return $ip             }             break         }         else {             Write-Output "Failed to start Kali VM $vmId."             break         }     } } catch {     Write-Output "Error creating Kali VM: $_" }  }
function Check-VMStatus {
param ( [string]$vmId )  try {     $response = python checkstatus.py $vmId     return $response.Trim() } catch {     Write-Output "Error checking VM status for VM $vmId: $_"     return $false }  }
function StartVm {
param ( [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string] $node, [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [int] $vmid )  try {     if (-not $vmid) {         $vmid = Read-Host "Bitte geben Sie den VM-ID ein, die Sie starten möchten"     }      $url = "$BASE_URL/nodes/$node/qemu/$vmid/status/start"     $headers = @{ "Authorization" = "PVEAPIToken=$API_TOKEN" }     $cloneParams = "node=$node&vmid=$vmid"      $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $cloneParams -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"          Write-Host "VM mit der ID $vmid wurde erfolgreich gestartet: $($response.Content)" }  catch {     Write-Error "Fehler beim Starten der VM: $_"     if ($_.Exception.Response) {         $reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream())         $responseText = $reader.ReadToEnd()         $reader.Close()         Write-Host "Serverantwort: $responseText"     } else {         Write-Host "Keine Antwort vom Server."     } }  }
function Get-VMIP {
param ( [string]$vmId ) try { $response = python getVM.py $vmId return $response.Trim() } catch { Write-Output "Error getting IP for VM $vmId: $_" return $null } }
function Main {
$vmType = Read-Host "Which VM type do you want to create (Kali/Windows)? " if ($vmType.ToLower() -eq 'kali') { $vmId = Read-Host "Enter the ID for Kali VM: " $kaliIP = Create-Kali-VM -vmId $vmId if ($kaliIP) { Write-Host "Kali VM $vmId has been successfully created."          $kaliIP = Get-VMIP -vmId $vmId         if ($kaliIP) {             Write-Host "IP address of Kali VM $vmId is: $kaliIP"             $sshUser = Read-Host "Enter the SSH username for Kali VM: "             Write-Host "To SSH into the Kali VM, use the following command from your terminal:"             Write-Host "ssh $sshUser@$kaliIP"         } else {             Write-Host "Failed to get IP address for Kali VM $vmId."         }     } } Main `
after execution of script i get :  PS C:\Users\Tets\Desktop\Powersehll-Skripte> ./build_lab.ps1 Which VM type do you want to create (Kali/Windows)? : Kali Enter the ID for Kali VM: : 906 C:\Users\Tets\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:1103: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host '.tkagit.com'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: rllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#tls-warnings warnings.warn( C:\Users\Tets\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packagesnnectionpool.py:1103: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host /en/latest/advanced-usage.html#tls-warnings warnings.warn( Kali VM 906 has been successfully created. C:\Users\Tets\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:1103: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host ''. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#tls-warnings warnings.warn( IP address of Kali VM 906 is Error retrieving IP addresses for VM 906: 500


See https://github.com/home-assistant/core/issues/95590 and https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.linkchecker/issues/57
